# Grub Disappearing Everytime i reboot

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

This started happening few days back. Everytime i restart my laptop, i get "Operating System Not found error". Used Boot-Repair Many times to reinstall Grub. But this keeps happening again. Attaching the Boot-Summary by Boot-Repair.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9540376/

Answer (score 0):

This is generally the message given by certain stupid bioses that check the MBR for a partition with the boot flag and refuse to boot the MBR if they don't find one.  Looking at your paste, you have the boot flag set on your linux partition, but it is a logical partition and the stupid bios only checks the primary partitions in the MBR.  Use `fdisk` or gparted and set the boot flag on one of the primary partitions ( 1-4 ) and that should fix it.

Comment: agreed. Any idea why Windows is displayed as "Recovery" by os-prober ? bug?

Comment: Thanks. I changed the boot flag of partition 4 and tried again changing partition1, doesn't seem to work.